# How to plot ROC curve for Local Outlier Factor algorithm?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc

I am trying to use [Local Outlier Factor (LOF)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.LocalOutlierFactor.html#examples-using-sklearn-neighbors-localoutlierfactor) algorithm, and would like to plot ROC curve. The problem is, the library that scikit-learn provides, does not produce a **score** for each prediction.

So, is there anyway I can solve this problem?

Comment: a ROC curve is only defined for probabilistic predictions. The mentioned algorithm however produces binary lables(0/1), so this won't work

Answer (score 3):

The attribute `negative_outlier_factor_` is pratically the -LOF as stated in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.LocalOutlierFactor.html#sklearn.neighbors.LocalOutlierFactor) and better in the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/neighbors/lof.py#L19). A common approach is to compute the ROC by assigning your predictions based on different values of the threshold. If you have your data in `df` with the labels within the column `'label'`, the code will be something like this:

```
def get_predictions(lof, threshold=1.5):
    return list(map(lambda x: -1 if x > threshold else 1, lof))

lof_ths = np.arange(1.3, 6., 0.1)
clf = LocalOutlierFactor(n_neighbors=30)
clf.fit_predict(df.drop(['label'], axis=1))
lofs = -clf.negative_outlier_factor_

plt.figure()
lw = 2
plt.xlim([0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate', fontsize=14)
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic', fontsize=16)

fpr = tpr = [0]

for ths in lof_ths:
    pred = get_predictions(lof, threshold=ths)
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(df.label, pred, labels=[-1,1]).ravel()
    fpr.append(fp / (fp + tn + .000001))
    tpr.append(tp / (tp + fn + .000001))

fpr.append(1)
tpr.append(1)
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='ROC Curve')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', label='Random Guessing', lw=lw, linestyle='--')
plt.legend(loc="lower right", fontsize=12)
```